# Not able to type in TextInput

Tags: react-native

```
export default class SignUp extends Component {

render() {
        const {Username, Password, signUpSuccessful} = this.state
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior = 'padding' style = {styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style = {styles.textInput}
                    placeholder = "Username"
                    onChangeText = {this.UpdateUsername}
                    //maxLength = {20}
                    value = {this.state.Username.value}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style = {styles.textInput}
                    placeholder = "Password"
                    onChangeText = {this.UpdatePassword}
                    maxLength = {20}
                    value = {this.state.Password.value}
                />
```

I am just starting out with react-native and dont really understand how TextInput works, could anyone tell me why I am unable to type in my TextInput fields?

I am trying to create a login page to store a user's username and password in a firebase database, the code for the storing has not been created yet. I am trying to get my TextInput fields to work properly first. It was able to work earlier before I added in the `value` lines for both of them but commenting them out now does not return them to a usable state so i suspect that the errors may come fro other aspects of the code but I am not sure what could be the problem as the code is very simple as of now.

Please let me know if you need to see other parts of the code as this is just a snippet of it.

Comment: Please share the UpdatePassword function code

Answer (score 0):

Manged to figure it out, it was the `KeyboardAvoidingView` that was causing issues, not sure why though, just working with `View` for now.